# Обязательно ли создавать всплывающее окно в onCreate?

Tags: android, java

Могу ли я создавать `PopupWindow` и отображать его из любого места программы или это обязательно делать в `onCreate`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нет необязательно, главное, чтобы к моменту создания `PopupWindow` был живой инстанс `Context`'а, чтобы к нему можно было привязать окошко